# Entities and relationships: How to configure my tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities, `WMDGCategory` and `WMDGActivity`. Their relationships are configured like this:

[image]

I want my tableview to display the `WMDGActivity`s grouped under sections title according to their associated `WMDGCategory.name`.

After failing miserably to achieve this with a single `NSFetchedResultsController` (and despite some posts claiming it can be done), I've decided to try two separate FRCs, `catFRC` and `actFRC`. These are currently declared like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    catFRC = [WMDGCategory MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:(YES) withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"name" delegate:nil];
    actFRC = [WMDGActivity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"catFRC.activities" delegate:nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

At this point my tableviewDataSource methods look like this. Pseudo code marked with this ----> shows the current state of my confusion.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[catFRC sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[catFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    WMDGActivity *activityForCell = // ----> the activities pointed to by the "WMDGCategory" relationship "activities", sorted by "name"

    cell.textLabel.text = activityForCell.name;


    return cell;
}
```

Can someone please tell me if I'm on the right track or not, and if I am please give me some guidance as to what exactly should constitute the argument for `WMDGActivity *activityForCell =`.

Thanks very much for your time!

**Edit following suggestions from mMo and Wain:**

Thanks to your on the point suggestions, I modified my code to use just the one FRC, `actFRC`, and it appears to work perfectly:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[actFRC sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[actFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionLabel = [[[actFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section]name];
    return [sectionLabel uppercaseString];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    WMDGActivity *thisActivity = [actFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisActivity.name;

    return cell;
}
```

My problem throughout this, in retrospect, stemmed from my difficulty in understanding that a call to `WMDGActivity.category` is a call to the `WMDGCategory` object associated with the `WMDGActivity` through the relationship. I know that must sound pretty stupid, but I had a great deal of trouble getting my head around the concept.

I owe you guys, and others here, a real debt of gratitude. Thanks!

Comment: Is the relationship an inverse one? As in, will each activity have a reference to the category it belongs to? If so, you would only need to make the one request (for the activities) and then you could look at grouping them by their respective category properties

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I should also have mentioned that I'm using MagicalRecord convenience classes for Core Data. However, I've tried using a single FRC, and I'm at a loss as to how to configure it.

Comment: Why not ask about using 1 FRC and describe what issue you are seeing?

Comment: Got it! Please see edit above. Upvote and green checkmark here for mMo, @Wain, please look for yours on yesterday's question. Thanks again!

Comment: @mMo-- can you put your suggestion into an answer, please?

Comment: @Wain--To answer your question, with my former code, the tableview was blank. Thanx again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each activity will have a reference to the category it belongs to, you would only need to make the one request (for the activities) and then you could look at grouping them by their respective category properties.